# How to deploy a C# Console app to Azure App Service using Github Actions

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy a C# Console app. (which inserts data from a third party API to Azure SQL) using Github Actions (push to Azure App Service), and I need some guidance for an option.

I pushed my C# code into Github from my Visual Studio solution in my laptop.

I chose this option ("Deploy .Net Core app to an Azure Web App") at Github Actions:
[image]

This is result that I got:
[image]

Did I choose wrong option here?

Do I need to create a Web App?

Comment: Can you explain why it is a console app? What you described should be a great case for Azure Functions.

Comment: @Lex Li I originally developed using Azure Functions, but due to the volume of data that I need to pull in, I decided to go with this option. If I just run Console App, it only takes about 5 min, instead of taking 5 hours using Azure Functions (as I had to create so many pipelines using Azure Data Factory and Web activities etc. It is such a mess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can deploy the console application into Azure app service using an Azure WebJob. To get complete idea on [WebJob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki). But the performance of the application is not guaranteed. To deploy using **[Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs)**. To deploy the application when the WebJob is already created use the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/).

**To schedule a WebJob**

To schedule the WebJob refer the [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON)